# Inheritance In Components Makes Build Error In Angular

Tags: angular, inheritance, build, angular-components

**I have a parent Component like this:**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main-parent',
    template: '',
})
export class ParentComponent {
    constructor(protected service) {
        service.doSomething();
    }
}
```

**and a child Component that extends parent:**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ChildService} from './services';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main-child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent{

    constructor(private _childService: ChildService) {
        super(_childService);
    }
}
```

**and in main.module.ts added these components:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ParentComponent,
        ChildComponent } from './components'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ParentComponent,
        ChildComponent,
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
    ...
    ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

**I build project with following command:**

```
npm run build
```

**And got this Error:**

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! proj.panel@0.0.0 build: ng build --aot --prod --stats-json
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the proj.panel@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-01-17T10_37_32_166Z-debug.log
```

**If I remove ParentComponent from main.module.ts, then get this Error:**

```
Cannot determine the module for class ParentComponent in
C:/Users/user/source/repos/proj/web-panel/app/main/components.ts!
Add ParentComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
```

**Other Stuff:**

1. if I run project with npm start command it works fine. only in build
   I got these Errors.
2. I ran build command with no aot (ng build --no-aot --prod) but
   errors are still there.
3. I dont use ParentComponent anywhere but for childs components to
   extend.

For Tooling issues:

- Angular version: 5.0.0
- Node version: 6.11.4
- Platform: Windows 10
- npm version: 5.6.0

Comment: area you available in teamviewer? seems to be a strange issue

Comment: The question lacks CLI version, while it's most relevant here. I'm not aware of any problems with inheritance that would lead to an issue like this one. *then get this Error* - of course, you need to remove the class from code base entirely. Is there an error with other options like `ng build --dev` and `ng build --no-aot`? There's no evidence that the issue is related to inheritance. Did you try to refactor children to not extend a class?

Comment: @Aravind no, but I have AnyDesk

Comment: chrome remote desktop?

Comment: @estus Angular CLI: 1.5.5, _you need to remove the class from code base entirely_, sorry, i didn't get you, what do you mean? _Is there an error with other options like ng build --dev and ng build --no-aot?_, yes, same as before, no difference. _There's no evidence that the issue is related to inheritance. Did you try..._ no, it gets too long to refactor, cuz there are many components, but I am sure, the only change was inherited components, after that I got Errors

Comment: If ParentComponent is a component and it is removed from a module, it should be removed from source code, otherwise an error is triggered. This is what should be done after refactoring (it possibly could be done with a regexp), and refactoring is the only way to to detect if inheritance is real problem. You can alternatively try to remove @Component AND/OR add `abstract` to ParentComponent. Again, there's no evidence that it is related to inheritance, CLI is a complex tool. The question requires a way to replicate the problem. Try to replicate it on another machine and OS, and also Stackblitz.

Comment: @moshtabamorsali reach me out in fb @ aravind2109

Comment: @Aravind sent you message

Comment: @estus ok, let me try something, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I searched a lot, and ask everyone I thought could help and nothing was solution.

Then I created a new project and copied all files from main project and magically errors get gone.

The problem was not about inheritance in components and still dont know what made errors

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to RAM consumption

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

- Clear all the `temp` and `%temp%` folders
- Use the following script to limit your RAM usage to 4GB

  ```
  node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --
  ```

Note: Please watch the path of your `node_modules`